# Matlab - Using two index arrays to operate on a sub-matrix

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to figure out how to access Matlab sub-arrays (part of an array) with a generic set of subscript vectors.

In general, the problem is defined as:
Given two n-dim endpoints of an array index (both size nd), one having the initial set of indices (startInd) and the other having the last set of indices (endInd), how to access the sub-matrix which is included between the pair of index-sets?

For example, I want to replace this:

```
Mat=rand(10,10,10,10);
Mat(2:7, 1:6, 1:6, 2:8) = 1.0;
```

With an operation that can accept any set of two n-dim vectors specifying the indices for the last operation, which is "abstractly" expressed as:

```
Mat=rand(10,10,10,10);
startInd=[2 1 1 2];
endInd  =[7 6 6 8];

IndexVar=???
Mat(IndexVar) = 1.0;
```

Thus I want to access the sub-matrix Mat(2:7, 1:6, 1:6, 2:8) using a variable or some other generic form that allows a generic n-dim. Preferably not a loop (as it is slow).

I have tried using something of this nature:

```
% Generate each index list separately:
nDims=length(startInd);
ind=cell(nDims,1);
for j=1:nDims
    ind{j}=startInd(j):1:endInd(j);
end

% Access the matrix:
S.type = '()';
S.subs = ind;
Mat=subsasgn(Mat,S,1.0)
```

This seems to get the job done, but is very slow and memory-expansive, but might give someone an idea...

Comment: An `eval` solution though it is not recommended: `eval (['Mat(' sprintf('%d:%d,', [startInd;endInd]) '1) = 1.0;']);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind looping over *dimensions* (which should be much faster than looping over array *entries*):

```
indexVar = arrayfun(@(a,b) colon(a,b), startInd, endInd, 'UniformOutput', false);
Mat(indexVar{:}) = 1;
```

This uses [`arrayfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html) (essentially a loop) to create a cell array with the indexing vectors, which is then expanded into a [comma-separated list](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html).

---

Now that I see your code: this uses the same approach, only that the loop is replaced by `arrayfun` and the comma-separated list allows a more natural indexing syntax instead of `subsasgn`.

Comment: You got it point on! I also checked the speed of it, it is pretty good.